# read text file using php (particular line)

Tags: php, phpunit

i am trying hard but not able to do it..any php expert share there knowledge...(I am really wondering how facebook has been build using PHP, if i am not able to do this simple thing :) Bad really bad )

I have below text file (sample.txt)

```
<Module>
title = "this is title" thumb ="http://www.example.com/thumb.jpg"
description ="this is the description of the title" 
screen ="http://www.example.com/screen.jpg"
<Content type="html" view="canvas">
<![CDATA[ 
<div>Hello world Canvas view</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goToView(dest) {
  var supported_views = gadgets.views.getSupportedViews();
  gadgets.views.requestNavigateTo(supported_views[dest]);
};
</script>
 <a href="javascript:goToView('home')" >Go to home view</a><br><br>
 ]]> 
 </Content>
 </Module>
```

Now i want to read the above sample.txt file using php and display it or store it in database.

e.g.

```
this is title - should go in $title variable
http://www.example.com/thumb.jpg  - should go in $thumb variable 
i just want only these four variables (title, thumb, description & screen)
```

here thing is in sample.txt all above four variables(title, thumb, description & screen) can be in separate line or on same line.

Can any expert help me out i tried lot but no luck...

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If you save your variables in an ini file, e.g: `sample.ini`

```
title = "this is title" 
thumb = "http://www.example.com/thumb.jpg"
description = "this is the description of the title" 
screen = "http://www.example.com/screen.jpg"
```

You can get the variables using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file).

```
$vars = parse_ini_file('sample.ini');
echo $vars['title'];
echo $vars['thumb'];
// etc.
```

Comment: thank you for reply ..but in sample.text may have so many other things as well..like
title = "this is title" thumb ="http://www.example.com/thumb.jpg"
description ="this is the description of the title" 
screen ="http://www.example.com/screen.jpg"
<body> <div>skfjsdf saf
ksdfj asfdl </div>
</body>
in this scenario will that work?

Comment: you can assign your HTML to a variable, like `$body = "<body> <div>skfjsdf saf ksdfj asfdl </div> </body>"`. But I think you need to separate PHP logic and HTML presentation.